# In protractor: How do I create a method that only sends keys I specify

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I have a method called populateProvidedValuesForNewMandate that looks like this

```
exports.populateProvidedValuesForNewMandate = (team, assignee, disputeValue, lawField, 
subjectOfDispute, party, fileReference, costUnit, clientUnit, sideEffect, comment) => {
  const teamInput = element(by.css('div#team input'));
  const assigneeInput = element(by.css('div#assignee input'));
  const disputeValueInput = element(by.id('dispute_value'));
  const lawFieldInput = element(by.css('div#law_field input'));
  const subjectOfDisputeInput = element(by.id('subject_of_dispute'));
  const partyInput = element(by.id('party'));
  const fileReferenceInput = element(by.id('file_reference'));
  const costUnitInput = element(by.css('div#cost_unit input'));
  const clientUnitInput = element(by.id('client_unit'));
  const sideEffectInput = element(by.css('div#side_effect input'));
  const mandateComment = element(by.id('mandate_comment'));

  // TODO: Figure out how to choose these dynamically as well
  // relevantCase, risReportRelevant, economicRelevance, activePassive
  const relevantCaseInput = element(by.css(".relevant_case input[value='no']"));
  const riskReportRelevantInput = element(by.css(".risk_report_relevant input[value='no']"));
  const economicRelevanceInput = element(by.css("label[for='economic_relevance']"));
  const activePassiveInput = element(by.css(".active_passive input[value='passive']"));

  teamInput.sendKeys(team);
  assigneeInput.sendKeys(assignee);
  disputeValueInput.sendKeys(disputeValue);
  lawFieldInput.sendKeys(lawField);
  subjectOfDisputeInput.sendKeys(subjectOfDispute);
  partyInput.sendKeys(party);
  fileReferenceInput.sendKeys(fileReference);
  costUnitInput.sendKeys(costUnit);
  clientUnitInput.sendKeys(clientUnit);
  sideEffectInput.sendKeys(sideEffect);
  mandateComment.sendKeys(comment);

 // TODO: Figure out how to choose these dynamically as well
 // relevantCase, risReportRelevant, economicRelevance, activePassive
 browser.actions().mouseMove(relevantCaseInput).doubleClick().perform();
 browser.actions().mouseMove(riskReportRelevantInput).click().perform();
 browser.actions().mouseMove(economicRelevanceInput).click().perform();
 browser.actions().mouseMove(activePassiveInput).click().perform();
};
```

and here is an example of its use case

```
    values.populateProvidedValuesForNewMandate(texts.DISPUTE_VALUE, texts.PARTY, texts.CLIENT_UNIT, 
    texts.SIDE_EFFECT, texts.COMMENT);
```

The method fills out the specified values that lie within a file called texts.js into the appropriate fields. The problem is that I get the error message: 'each key must be a number of string; got undefined' meaning that this method doesn't work because I have to send the keys for each specified variable in the method.

I really want to avoid sending empty strings for this method (especially because it won't work, I've tried it out -> I get a error from the app itself, not protractor/selenium).

How can I turn this method into one that only considers the specified variables in the test cases.
Also as you can see from my comment, I am trying to figure out how to do this for the checkbox and radio buttons as well. If anyone has a hint, I'd really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, only you can answer the question. Because there are hundreds of ways to fo this, and some may work better than another. So to us it's silly to make guesses which way is the best for you. So I'll give one example and hopefully you can take it from here

One way is to make the method accept an object and check if a property has been passed

```
function fillForm(obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty('team')) teamInput.sendKeys(team);
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty('assignee')) assigneeInput.sendKeys(assignee);
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty('disputeValue')) disputeValueInput.sendKeys(disputeValue);
// ...
}
```

and then call it

```
fillForm({
  assignee: texts.ASIGNEE,
  disputeValue: texts.DISPUTE_VALUE
})
```

so it will skip sending keys to team field